# Populate chartjs ajax with datetime fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, chart.js

I'm trying  to make a chart with chart.js. I have php code which brings back datetime data with an ajax call. The problem is, it doesn't show any data, and it doesn't show errors. I used console.log() to see if it is something wrong with the php code, but it seems right.

**PHP CODE**

```
require_once 'core.php';

$sql = sprintf("SELECT entradas, salida_laborable FROM tiempo where cod_fecha = 60");
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();
$connect->close();
print json_encode($data);
```

**Ajax/Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
     url : "php_action/horas_chart.php",
     type : "GET",
     success : function(data){
     console.log(data);

     var cod_fecha = [];
     var entradas  = [];
 
     for(var i in data) {
        cod_fecha.push(data[i].cod_fecha);
        entradas.push(data[i].entradas);
     }

   var chartdata = {
       labels: name,
         datasets: [
            {
                   label: 'Promedio',
                backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                    data: entradas
                            }
                        ]
                    };

    var ctx = $("#canvas");

    var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
    });
  },
error : function(data) {
}
});
});
```

This is the result:

[image: This is the result]

Thanks, I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

As i remember charjs expect Date() object for Date entry
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html
so you can try

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  entradas.push(new Date(data[i].entradas));
}
```